# Open winmail.dat files on Android

Tags: files

How can I read `winmail.dat` files on my Android?

I currently get an error message that I do not have an app to view it.

Answer (score 1):

`winmail.dat` files are Microsoft proprietary files created by Microsoft Outlook and Exchange. Usually Email apps from Microsoft should be able to handle such files. However searching for [**winmail.dat** in Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=winmail.dat&c=apps) shows that several other apps are claiming to be able to open such files.

If you receive such files the sender is using Outlook via Exchange and your contact is misconfigured. Contact the sender and ask to change your contact to plain text format then you will no longer receive such attachments.

Comment: Another option might be to open in webmail?  It's been a while, but I recall they should be readable that way.